# Getting files and directories from CLI in Python

Tags: python, file, command-line-interface

I've written a command-line app in Python that allows the end user to specify files and directories to search in. I use argparse to parse the arguments.

Here's a simple example:

```
$ app --src file.txt dir/
```

The output would look something like this:

```
['file.txt', 'dir/file1.txt', 'dir/file2.txt', 'dir/file3.txt']
```

The function I wrote to do this looks a bit messy to me, and I would like to refactor it into a more concise form if possible.

My function is as follows:
(Updated, should work and looks a bit better now)

```py
def get_files(src: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    """Return a list of files"""

    files_total: list[str] = []

    for entry in src:
        if os.path.isdir(entry):
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(entry):
                for name in files:
                    files_total.append((os.path.join(root, name)))
                for name in dirs:
                    files_total.append((os.path.join(root, name)))
        elif os.path.isfile(entry):
            files_total.append(entry)
        else:
            sys.exit(f"Cannot access '{entry}': No such file or directory")

    return files_total
```

With the function as it is now, everything seems to work as expected. But is there a more elegant, Pythonic way to achieve this?

The part I don't like in my (updated) function is the nested for loops, but I should probably just live with it and move on.

Thank you.

Comment: 1. This is not "from stdin", this is "from cli". And since it's not about parsing the cli args, I'd skip that part altogether. 2. How deep you want this? It seems you only do one level of depth. Since you're using `os`, there's just `os.walk`, no need to have a separate scandir etc, 3. You're doing files_from_... = instead of .append, so the loop will only get last dir's and last file's results (you test on one file and one dir so you didn't notice it)

Comment: 4. What do you if isfile is weird - you're just adding all stuff from src? But src is just the original list of paths. This would also mean `dir/` itself would be included in the result. You should probably just append the `entry` itself

Comment: @h4z3 I've updated my post according to your suggestions. You're right, I didn't test it with multiple directories and I don't know why I didn't use `append()`. Now it works and at least looks better than before. Regarding your last comment, I'm not sure what the results were before because I used `filter()` to extract certain file types, but testing it now without my `filter()` function gives me the correct result. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version seems quite *pythonic* already. The 3 "ifs" can be replaced by a single "if elif else". And to make it more modern, I would suggest using `pathlib` instead of `os.path` for what it's worth.

```py
from pathlib import Path

def get_files(src: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    """Return a list of files"""

    files_from_dir: list[str] = []
    files_from_file: list[str] = []

    for entry in src:
        path = Path(entry)

        if path.is_dir():
            try:
                files_from_dir.extend(str(file) for file in path.iterdir() if file.is_file())
            except OSError as e:
                print(f"Cannot access '{entry}': {e}")
        elif path.is_file():
            files_from_file.append(str(path))
        else:
            print(f"Cannot access '{entry}': No such file or directory")

    return [*files_from_dir, *files_from_file]
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Somehow I had tunnel vision and didn't realise that I actually needed `elif` ... `else` to make this work. I'll definitely take a closer look at `pathlib`, I really like your approach. One question I still have, should the `OSError` be raised due to memory issues when working with too many files? Should I use it inherently when working with directories from the end user?

Comment: You're welcome. And you're probably right, I don't know if the OSError exception is justified here. I used it out of habit. However, you can adjust it afterwards according to exceptions that you encounter. For example you can definitely get a PermissionError ([Errno 13] Permission denied) when you try to access a file and you don't have enough rights.